# Any good heuristics for grouping a 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, heuristics

I have a two dimensional array that I'd like to group. I could group it in equally spaced bins, but then I would have some bins with only one data point and others with 100s. Is there any good grouping heuristics (specifically for python) that I can do to make unequal sized bins but contain roughly the same number of data points?

The best solution for me would be bins with a min and max number of data points to include, that way my grouping remains flexible. However, I do not know where to start with making such a heuristic.

Here is a plot of the 2d data I'd like to group:
[image: My Data]
EDIT: I want the grouping bins to be 2 dimensional as well

Answer (score 1):

You might want to google for `array-partitioning` (`rectangular-partitioning`), sometimes `workload-partitioning`.

The 2d-case can already be NP-hard, but there are some good algorithms, which seem to be very important in regards to workload-partitioning in parallel- or distributed-systems.

Not python, but a very complete library towards this is: [SPart - Spatially Located Workload Partitioner](http://tda.gatech.edu/software/spart/index.html).

The resources on that page might link to more research in this area.